# ShortcutBadger not working when app is killed or in the background

Tags: android, firebase

I want to change the badger number when I receive payload data message. I can receive the message, but I can't change the number. It's my code:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       //  handleNotification();
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        databaseHelper.addRow();
        int numberOfNot = databaseHelper.getNumber();
        ShortcutBadger.applyCount(getApplicationContext(), numberOfNot);
}
```

I tried to set `numberOfNot = 10`, but it was not working.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, the badge is not updating when the app is in the background or killed.